# Merging lines, issue

Tags: line, splitting, mergeshapes

I use qgis 2.18. I've merged two lines into one with the merging tool from advanced toolset.
When I cut off a small part of the line, I see the original lines again?
In these two lines I have the same ID, and it should not be.
I try to make road network with start and end of roads nodes. In that reason Aeuquilibrae plugin cannot create Nodes on that merged line. This is not only one line, this is used like example.This is only the case with such lines. My question is: how to merge a line from several lines without ghosts?

[image]

[image]

The yellow line was the original line. 
Picture below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Merge Selected Features` tool creates a multipart objects. You can check it by `Identify Features` tool.

[image]

Use **Merge Lines** tool instead. It is in `QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector geometry tools`.

Comment: I did not manage to merged them with this Merge Lines tool

Comment: @nagib Is there anything I can do to clarify the process? Do you see any error?

Comment: thank you for trying to help me, there is no error , merge lines tool not merging lines, I see two parts again. Do You mean, on already merged line to use Merged Lines tools?